# PyQt5 Laying Properly

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I've already looked heavily to see how to properly layer my ui and haven't found out how to layer my windows so it comes off looking somewhat like this:

[image]

I want to have my background layer which I have set as a label with an image and then have a qt widget with login centered in the middle of it almost popping out at the user however when I do this it comes out with the widget behind my main window, it doesn't align properly and it also doesnt "follow" the window when I move it around image provided:

[image]

```py
import PyQt5.QtWidgets
import sys


class LoginPanel(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setFixedSize(600,400)
        self.setWindowFlags(PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QWidget {
                background-color: #CBCAB7;
                border-radius: 50px;
            }
        """) 
        self.show()


class Auth(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Login")

        self.setFixedSize(1200,800)
        self.setWindowFlags(PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
        self.setWindowIcon(PyQt5.QtGui.QIcon("assets\\login.ico"))
        self.background = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLabel("", self) 

        self.layout = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(LoginPanel(), 0, 1)
        self.set_background()
        self.show()
        #self.layout.setAlignment(PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    

    def set_background(self):
        img = PyQt5.QtGui.QPixmap("assets\\background.png")
        pixmap = img.scaled(self.width(), self.height())
        self.background.setPixmap(img)
        self.background.resize(self.width(), self.height())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    a = Auth()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Here is my current code, I just wanted some help sense while looking online I was unable to find any great examples or references.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: https://hastebin.com/qizixijefo.rb Here  is my current code which I've uploaded to hastebin

Comment: It seems that you have not read the SO rules, the MRE should not depend on an external link, but should be part of your post, so I recommend editing and adding it there. Also read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: Ill fix right now sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is not to create a new window but to set it as a child of the window, and to raise it above any other child, you must use `raise_()` method, also add a `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` to establish the floating window effect:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


class LoginPanel(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(600, 400)

        self.container = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.container.setStyleSheet(
            """
            background-color: #CBCAB7;
            border-radius: 50px;
        """
        )

        offset = 30
        self.container.setGeometry(
            self.rect().adjusted(offset, offset, -offset, -offset)
        )
        effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(
            blurRadius=50, offset=QtCore.QPointF(0, 0)
        )
        self.container.setGraphicsEffect(effect)

        lay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        lay.setContentsMargins(2 * offset, 2 * offset, 2 * offset, 2 * offset)
        lay.addRow("Username:", QtWidgets.QLineEdit())
        lay.addRow("Email:", QtWidgets.QLineEdit())


class Auth(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Login")

        self.setFixedSize(1200, 800)
        self.setWindowFlags(
            QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint
        )
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("assets\\login.ico"))
        self.background = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.set_background()

        self.panel = LoginPanel(self)
        self.center_panel()

    def set_background(self):
        img = QtGui.QPixmap("assets\\background.png")
        pixmap = img.scaled(self.size())
        self.background.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.background.resize(self.size())

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.center_panel()

    def center_panel(self):
        g = self.panel.geometry()
        g.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
        self.panel.setGeometry(g)
        self.panel.raise_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = Auth()
    a.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't realize how much I was over-complicating it. This is for sure a better method. Thank you so much